# How to pass row $event to bootstrap modal in angular 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I am trying to delete a record from a table. The user clicks the delete button and it opens a confirmation box. The user clicks on the delete button in the box and then it should delete. I want to pass the row's $event to bootstrap modal so that I can get the cell details and process delete. Below is the code

```
<td>
    <a href="#" style="color:brown" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
    </a>
</td>

<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    Confirm?
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Are you sure that you want to delete the record?
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok" (click)="deleteExpense($event)">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How to achieve this? Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1):

Better to create one Delete modal component for the same instead of using same code again and again
here is my code for the same , just pass the data of row and use like this

```
<delete (deleteFun)="DeleteElement(Number)" [pk]='Number'></delete>
```

you can see here working example

http://plnkr.co/edit/AiDiNl8SrSKIwDUYWl50?p=preview

PS: for more components see here

> https://github.com/MrPardeep/Angular2-DatePicker

Answer (score 0):

I've created some components for doing that in my application. I'll try sharing the ideas with you.
First, I would recommend you to use ng2-bootstrap that provides a better way to do modals in angular2.
With that I place, I created a generic confirmation modal that can also confirm actions to a certain entity (witch would be your $event). It's something like this:

HTML

```
<div bsModal #modalControl="bs-modal" id="confirmation-dialog" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" #registerModal>
  <div class="modal-dialog register-modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="panel panel-transparent">
        <div class="panel-heading">
                    <span class="title">
                        {{ title }}
                    </span>
          <div class="pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalControl.hide()">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          {{ message }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="javascript:;" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="modalControl.hide()" class="btn btn-link">voltar</a>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onButtonClick($event)">{{ buttonLabel }}</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Typescript

```
@Component({
  selector: 'confirmation-dialog',
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: 'confirmation-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['confirmation-dialog.component.css']
})
export class ConfirmationDialogComponent {
  @ViewChild('modalControl') modalControl: ModalDirective;

  @Input() title = '';
  @Input() message = '';
  @Input() buttonLabel = 'Yes';
  @Output() confirmedActionOnEntity = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() confirmedAction = new EventEmitter();
  entity: any;

  confirmActionOnEntity(entity: any) {
    this.entity = entity;
    this.modalControl.show();
  }

  confirmAction() {
    this.modalControl.show();
  }

  isShown() {
    return this.modalControl === undefined ? false : this.modalControl.isShown;
  }

  onButtonClick(event: any) {
    if(this.entity !== undefined && this.entity !== null) {
      this.confirmedActionOnEntity.emit(this.entity);
      this.entity = undefined;
    } else {
      this.confirmedAction.emit(event);
    }
    this.modalControl.hide();
  }
}
```

With this component in place you can use it like this:

```
<confirmation-dialog title="my confirmation" message="are you sure you want to do this?" (confirmedActionOnEntity)="methodThatActuallyDoesSomething($event)" #deleteConfirmationDialog></confirmation-dialog>

<entity-component (delete)="deleteConfirmationDialog.confirmActionOnEntity($event)"><entity-component>
```

This little component has done magic for me. I've used it a million times by now. Even created inline confirmation for deleting in rows using the same idea.

I hope this helps you.